# Do sparks from a cigarette lighter fix dead zones on touch screen?

Tags: physics, mobile-phones, electronics

There are many forums posts and videos on the "lighter trick" which fixes touch screens dead zones (at least temporarily) such as The YouTube video [*Nokia Lumia Touchscreen Dead Zone Fix With Igniter (Lighter)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hr4_lZCVlWU) purports to show a phone with a large "dead zone" in the middle of the screen where it is unresponsive to touch. Then a cigarette lighter is sparked, and the dead zone is working again.

This is just one of several sites to make such a claim: e.g. [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1LL0vVcov0), [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1eO-iW6mVg), [[3]](https://devrant.com/rants/1294725/did-you-know-you-can-fix-touchscreen-dead-zones-with-an-electric-lighter-i-just)

I cannot understand how this might work.

Can a cigarette lighter ignition be used this way to fix dead zones on capacitive touch screens?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the title a little bit. It's not just windows phone though, there's many videos claiming this across many devices. Granted, most I see are android. The video in the post is just the most concise one I can find.

Comment: Frankly all the swapping between apps in that vid make it hard to see that it's not a software problem. Somewhat more convincing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VERfODYHX3g

Comment: The why question is probably better on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I focussed the question.

Comment: I think physics tag is not much  relevant here. Although heat is involved but charging and discharging of capacitors is concerned field of electrical and electronics engineering.

Comment: That is interesting. Most touch screens are capacitive sensing these days. It might be possible that a there is a calibration issue where part of the sensor grid has fallen out of spec, causing a dead zone, and a electromagnetic pulse (small) from a piezoelectric lighter might temporarily fool the software into being more sensitive in that area. But I’m not confident this is the case.